# Graphing attributes if they fulfill a condition

Tags: qgis, csv, import, conditional

I have a dataset with schools, school coordenates, if the school is private or public and a variable containing the decile of attainment of the school in a test.

I am trying to map schools in a city and colour them by their performance level (I have a variable that looks at decile), but I would like to have different colours for the scales of public schools and private schools.

I tried doing this using the same variable for both types of schools and then using an if (I could not achieve graphing using conditionals in QGIS)

I created a separate variable in my dataset for each type of school and the decile in which they perform. I just multiplied the indicator variable for public and for private by their decile level, so I have a variable with the deciles for private schools in which all public schools have 0. This did not work because when I tried to graph private schools, all the public schools appeared in the graph, but as zeroes.

I tried constructing the dataset with missing values instead of zeroes. And when I try to import it QGIS (2.10) imports it as something that looks like an attribute table (even if I specified the coordinates).

Answer (score 1):

You are likely looking for [Rule Based Styling](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/uk/docs/training_manual/vector_classification/classification.html),section 3.5 towards the bottom of the linked QGIS help page:

> Open the Layer Properties dialog for the desired layer. 
>   Switch to the Style tab. 
>   Switch the classification style to Rule-based. 
>   Click the Add rule button: (green plus sign). A new dialog then appears. 
>   Click the ellipsis ... button next to the Filter text area. Using the
>   query builder that appears, enter the criterion, (for example, "school" = 'private' AND "testCriteria" > 10 AND "testCriteria" < 0) click Ok and choose
>   your symbology 
>   **note the double quotes around column names and single quotes around strings** 
>   Add another criteria, and another until you have fulfilled your needs.